# How to install pinax stripe over my existing project?

Tags: django, stripe-payments, pinax

I have been developing a django project which was built on the top of pinax-accounts . I also need the feature of stripe payments which has come recently in with pinax-stripe-payments. So how do I download pinax-stripe in such a way that its features such as billing, payments etc that come ready made in its front end templates and backend become integrated with my existing project?

Or will i have to make my entire project from scratch on the top of pinax-stripe project or how?

Answer (score 0):

The default pinax-stripe package doesnt come with any templates.
The best option for you would be to import the source code of pinax payment app (with the front end template ) into your main app and edit the templates if you need.
The backend code would already be there.